# manipulating multi dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

i have this json data

```
{"results":{
    "result":{
        "count":182,
        "firsthit":1,
        "lasthit":182,
        "name":"Primary Schools",
        "schoolhit":[{
            "districtno":25,
            "name":"ADMIRALTY PRIMARY SCHOOL",
            "precinct":"Woodlands",
            "region":"North",
            "zipcode":738907},
            {
            "districtno":27,
            "name":"AHMAD IBRAHIM PRIMARY SCHOOL",
            "precinct":"Yishun",
            "region":"North",
            "zipcode":768643},
            {
            "districtno":20,
            "name":"AI TONG SCHOOL",
            "precinct":"Sin Ming",
            "region":"North",
            "zipcode":579646},
            {
            "districtno":19,
            "name":"ANCHOR GREEN PRIMARY SCHOOL",
            "precinct":"Sengkang",
            "region":"North",
            "zipcode":544969}]
        }
    }
}
```

im still learning to understand... but could anyone point me on the right direction. I would like to achieve this using PHP the following...

```
<select>
<?php print "<option value=\"$districtno\">$name</option>";?><br />
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
$data = json_decode($json)->{'results'}->{'result'}->{'schoolhit'};

foreach ($data as $school) {
    echo "<option value=" . $school->{'districtno'} . ">" . $school->{'name'} . "</option>";
}
```

Obviously adapt the output to your needs but given your json that should fill out the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `json_decode`, and then iterate through that array.